# If a function is constant on some domain and differentiable, is it constant on a larger domain?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $f(x) = C$ on $(a,b)$ and differentiable does this imply that $f(x) = C$ on the whole domain ($\mathbb{R}$)?

Comment: What is the domain? If its anything larger than $(a,b)$, then no.

Comment: Yeah, larger than (a,b).

Comment: Can you give me a counter-example?

Comment: Take $f(x)=C$ on $(a,b)$ and $f(b)=C+1$.

Comment: Isn't the derivative at defined at b?

Comment: I was interpreting this as "$f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$" but now I realize you probably meant the whole domain

Comment: Yes, I was talking about the domain.

Comment: The whole of it.

Comment: [Even if it is infinitely differentiable it is not necessarily constant.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It is possible to "patch" functions together in a differentiable way. For instance, let the domain be $[-1,1]$,
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}0,&\ x<0 \\ x^2,&\ x\geq0 \end{cases}
$$
Then $f$ is differentiable (you can check that it is differentiable at $0$ by looking at the two side derivatives), constant in part of the domain, but non-constant in the whole.

A variation of this example can achieve the same even if "infinitely differentiable" is required. Only when we get to "analytic", will "constant on an interval" imply "constant everywhere".

Comment: What is an example function for infinitely differentiable?

Comment: Typically, $e^{-1/x^2}$ on the right, and zero on the left.

Comment: Ok, I understand, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for adding the extra bit about analyticity! The question had made me curious.

Answer (score 1):

Take $f(x)=0$ if $x\in (-1,0)$, and $f(x)=x^2$ if $x\in[0,1)$. Then $f$ is differentiable on $(-1,1)$ and non constant.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are functions like $f(x)=e^{-1/x}$ are Smooth ( though not Real-analytic). You can define $g(x):=f(x)+c$ which will be differentiable everywhere; take the value $c$ in an open interval $(a,b)$ ( just take $-\infty <a<b<0$).